# Show, that $ U = \left\{ u \in W_p^2 (\mathbb{R}_+)\ | \ u(0) = 0 \right\}$ is a closed subspace of $W_p^2 (\mathbb{R}_+)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, complete-spaces

I want to prove, that $U$ is a complete space.

I already proved, that $W_p^2 (\mathbb{R}_+)$ is complete.

But, as far as I've understood, you need to additionally show that $U$ is also a closed space, in order to claim that $U$ is complete, too.

But how should I do this? Because all the proofs of closeness I know would rely on knowing whether $U$ is complete or not (because I construct a sequence of elements from $U$, which I want to find out that it's limit belongs to $U$, too).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to find a continuous linear map of which this set is the kernel.

Comment: You have to show that if $(u_n)\in U^{\mathbb N}$ converges to $u\in W_p^2(\mathbb R_+)$, then $u\in U$, which is quite straightforward by continuity of the trace function...

Comment: @Surb What do you mean by trace function? And why is it obvious that $u \in U$? I only proved that $W_p^2 (\mathbb(R)_+)$ is complete, this does not guarantee us that $u \in U$, it only guarantees us that $u \in W_p^2 (\mathbb{R}_+)$

Comment: The trace function $T:W^{1,p}(\Omega )\to L^p(\partial \Omega )$ is defined by $$T(u)=u|_{\partial \Omega },$$ which is continuous. In your case, $$T:W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^+)\to L^2(\{0\})$$ is defined as $$T(u)=u(0).$$ Since it's continuous, if $(u_n)\in U^{\mathbb N}$ converges to $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^+)$, then by continuity of $T$, $0=u_n(0)=T(u_n)\to T(u)=0=u(0)$.